# How to retrieve current NHibernate Session object from Castle ActiveRecord SessionScope

Tags: nhibernate, session, object, castle-activerecord, session-scope

I have an open Castle ActiveRecord SessionScope.
I need to use the nhibernate session wrapped into SessionScope.

How can i retrieve the current NHibernate Session Object from SessionScope?

thank you very much for the replies.

[update]
i have this code

```
    ISession session = SessionScope.Current.GetSession( );
```

but i don't know what pass to the GetSession parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the Activerecord SessionScope can handle multiple factories for different types, but if you are not utilizing that I think you would be good to pass in any type of class that is a persisted one:

```
ISession session = SessionScope.Current.GetSession( typeof ( YourClass ) );
```

Comment: thanks @jishi but i have this error: the key isn't in the collection.

Comment: Are you using ActiveRecordFacility with Windsor?

Comment: thank you @jishi, i'm not using ActiveRecordFacility with Windsor, but i tryed a solution, i tested it and goes fine. thank you again.

Comment: Downvote because the solution did not work when I tried it. The higher voted answer did work.

Answer (score 9):

I resolved it with this code:

```
        ISessionFactoryHolder holder = ActiveRecordMediator.GetSessionFactoryHolder();
        ISessionScope activeScope = holder.ThreadScopeInfo.GetRegisteredScope();
        ISession session = null;
        var key = holder.GetSessionFactory(typeof(ActiveRecordBase));
        if (activeScope == null)
        {
            session = holder.CreateSession(typeof(ActiveRecordBase));
        }
        else
        {
            if (activeScope.IsKeyKnown(key))
                session = activeScope.GetSession(key);
            else
                session = holder.GetSessionFactory(typeof(ActiveRecordBase)).OpenSession();
        }
```